# How can a @IBDesignable UI component be implemented into a SwiftUI view?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to use ['Cards' component](https://github.com/PaoloCuscela/Cards) in my project.

This project is an iOS app created on Xcode 13 using SwiftUI interface and not storyboard.

Cards has been installed using cocoapods.

The documentation can't help because it is assuming that the project uses the storyboard interface and not SwiftUI.

I tried the following:

```
import SwiftUI
import Cards

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let card: CardHighlight = {
        let card = CardHighlight(frame: .zero)
        return card
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        card
    }
}
```

But I get the 2 following errors on 'card' line:

> Return type of property 'body' requires that 'CardHighlight' conform
> to 'View'

> Static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'CardHighlight' conform to
> 'View'

This `CardHighlight` has been created using `@IBDesignable`.

**How should it be added to `View` component?**

Comment: All Cards are UIView, so you need to use UIViewRepresentable wrapper to insert them into SwiftUI views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299030/asperi) commented:

> All Cards are UIView, so you need to use UIViewRepresentable wrapper
> to insert them into SwiftUI views.

Indeed this worked, thank you Asperi.

Here how I created the wrapper for anyone interested:

```
// CardView.swift
import SwiftUI
import Cards

struct CardView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CardHighlight {
        CardHighlight()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: CardHighlight, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

Then simply used this new view on any other view:

```
// ContentView.swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CardView()
    }
}
```